# Why I cannot declare a class method with class in Swift protocol with AnyObject constraint?

Tags: swift

Why Swift compiler won't allow this:

```
protocol A: AnyObject {
    class func foo()
}
```

I understand in this case:

```
protocol A {
    class func foo()
}
```

... because A can be implemented by value types (e.g. structs) as well, so it won't make sense.

But in first example, because I specified `AnyObject` constraint - only classes can implement it, and I don't see why would it be an issue.

I know we can use `static` instead.

But my question is why we cannot use `class` in the scenario where we have `AnyObject` constraint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess because [*"Classes can use the class keyword instead, to allow subclasses to override the superclass’s implementation of that method"*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/methods#Type-Methods) refers specifically to classes and you have a protocol.  A class that conforms to a protocol can use `class` or `static` to conform to a protocol with a `static` function requirement depending on whether they want to allow subclasses to override or not.

Comment: While it isn't obvious that this is allowed, it is kind of neat; It allows implementers to choose whether to provide a `class` or `static` implementation and also doesn't require you to limit your protocol to `AnyObject` if you don't otherwise need to (ie you don't require reference type semantics)